# Radius of convergence of a sequence of complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $\{a_n \}_{n=0}^\infty $ be a sequence of complex number with $\sum |a_n| < \infty $ and $\sum n|a_n| = \infty $. Determine the radius of convergence $ \sum a_n 2^n z^n$.

What I still thinking of are

The term $\sum |a_n| < \infty $ means that $a_n$ is converge, and I'm about to use
$ \lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}|$ . But i think this doesn't help much.
I really need your helps.

Answer (score 1):

From $\sum_n|a_n|<\infty$ you know that $\sum_na_nz^n$ converges at $z=1$. This means that the radius of convergence of $\sum_na_nz^n$ is at least $1$.

If it were strictly larger, then its term by term derivative would also converge at $z=1$, but that is $\sum_nna_nz^n$, which doesn't.

Therefore, the radius of $\sum_na_nz^n$ is exactly $1$.

Thus the radius of convergence of $\sum_na_n2^nz^n$ is $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_n:=|a_n|$.

Since $\sum |a_n| < \infty$ , the root test gives $\lim \sup b_n^{1/n} \le 1.$

Since $\sum n|a_n| = \infty$ , the root test gives $\lim \sup n^{1/n}b_n^{1/n}= \lim \sup b_n^{1/n} \ge  1.$.

Hence $\lim \sup b_n^{1/n}=1$.

Therefore $ \lim \sup |a_n 2^n|^{1/n}=2.$

The radius of convergence $=1/2.$